# How to stream screen to Raspberry with Java?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I want to create an app to stream desktop screen to rasberry and then on tv. I chose java for streaming side (I dont know if it's good and effective solution) but I got stuck. I dont know how to properly do that. Yesterday I tried to just create a video by JpegImagesToMovie lib but i got low framerates(because of saving screenshots). I dont know how this should looks like. Should I only send screenshots to rasberry and catch it on this side and make a video, or should I join screenshots and then send it? Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Anyone used gstreamer?  Maybe this could solve my problems?

Comment: It appears that GStreamer uses C/C++, if you are familiar or willing to learn C++, that might be able to help. Here is the link to [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/helloworld.html).

Comment: If you prefer to use Java, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592664/desktop-tcp-streaming-java) might help.

Comment: If you want felxibility in terms of language choice, you might want to look at [this](https://getstream.io/docs/java/).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanArendt i will take a look at your links. I think i take java over c/c++ ;) I also think about Kotlin, never do anything in this, could be nic to learn that.

Comment: Good luck, if you have any questions feel free to ask.